# ActiveRecord::PreparedStatementInvalid in ArticlesController

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to make an mini blog with Ruby on Rails. I have encountered this error when I wanted to add search action on articles_controller.rb. Search form is located at navbar. If the search form is blank, there is no error. If I typed something in the search form, this error,`wrong number of bind variables (2 for 1) in: text LIKE ? or title LIKE` appears.

**error log**

> > Started GET "/articles/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=kawaii&commit=Search" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-02-21 13:21:02 +0900
> >        (0.4ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
> >       ↳ /Users/igarashinobuo/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
> >     Processing by ArticlesController#search as HTML
> >       Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>"kawaii", "commit"=>"Search"}
> >     Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 14ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

ActiveRecord::PreparedStatementInvalid (wrong number of bind variables (2 for 1) in: text LIKE ? or title LIKE):

app/models/article.rb:8:in `search'
app/controllers/articles_controller.rb:23:in`search'

**controllers/articles_controller.rb**

```
def search
    if params[:search].blank?
      @articles = Article.all
    else
      @articles = Article.search(params)
    end
  end
```

**models/article.rb**

```
  def self.search(params)
      articles = Article.where("text LIKE ? or title LIKE", "%# 
      {params[:search]}%", "%#{params[:search]}%") if params[:search].present?
      articles
  end
end
```

**views/articles/search.html.erb**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col-md-10">
    <h1>
      記事リスト</h1>
    <p>
      <%= link_to '新規記事作成', new_article_path, class:'btn btn-lg btn-info' %>
    </p>

    <table class="table table-hover table-striped table-responsive-xs table-info">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Title</th>
          <th>Text</th>
          <th colspan="3">Editing Options</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <% @articles.each do |article| %>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <%= article.title %>
            </td>
            <td>
              <%= truncate(article.text, length: 75) %>
            </td>
            <td>
              <%= link_to 'SHOW', article_path(article), class: 'btn btn-sm btn-info' %>
            </td>
            <td>
              <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_article_path(article), class: 'btn btn-sm btn-warning' %>
            </td>
            <td>
              <%= link_to 'Delete',article_path(article), class: 'btn btn-sm btn-danger', method: :Delete, data: {confirm: '本当に削除しますか ?'} %>
            </td>
          </tr>
        <% end %>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <p>
      <%= link_to 'Home', welcome_index_path, class: 'btn btn-sm btn-info' %>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="col"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're missing an ? for the second parameter of your query:

```
  def self.search(params)
      articles = Article.where("text LIKE ? or title LIKE ?", "%# 
      {params[:search]}%", "%#{params[:search]}%") if params[:search].present?
      articles
  end
```